# Can't download base64 encoded files in IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, download

I've got the following Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'AJAX.aspx/DownloadFile',
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data)
    {
        window.location.href = 'data:txt/octet-stream;base64, ' + data.d;
    },
    error: function (x, e)
    {
        alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
    }
});
```

And here's my server side code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string DownloadFile(){
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=b.txt");
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/b.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    byte[] data=new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);        
    fs.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```

I've got two problems here:

1. In Opera,Firefox and Chrome I can download the file composed of the base64 binary data sent from the server. The only problem with them is that the file name is the browser default.In Opera it's "default", in Chrome "download" and in Firefox something like this:"lpyQswKF.part". How can I assign the name manually?
2. In IE I get the following error:"The webpage cannot be displayed.Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed."

Answer (score 1):

You can assign file name like this:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");

a.download = "file name";

a.href = 'data:txt/octet-stream;base64,' + data.d;

document.body.appendChild(a);

a.click();
```

I'm still searching how to make it working in IE